# Distribution of X

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

So I'm new when it comes to discrete mathematics and I'd need a complete answer to this problem, to see how should I answer exercises like this one.

The probability to log on a computer from a remote terminal is 0.7. Let X denote the number of attempts that must be made to gain access to the computer. Find:

(a) The distribution of X and prove that is correctly defined
(b) The expected value of attempts needed to gain access
(c) The probability that at most three attempts, respectively at least two attempts must be made to gain access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X=n$ iff the first $n-1$ attempts result in failure to access the computer and the next attempt results in success. Assuming independence of the attempts we get $P(X=n)=(0.3)^{n-1} (0.7)$. This is true for $n=1,2,...$ and these probabilities specify the distribution of $X$. The expectation of $X$ is given by $EX= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} nP(X=n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n(0.3)^{n-1} (0.7)$. The answer to c) is $P(X \leq 3)= (0.7) +(0.3) (0.7) +(0.3)^{2} (0.7)$.

To compute the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n(0.3)^{n-1} (0.7)$ use the following formula $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} anr^{n-1}=\frac a {(1-r)^{2}}$.

Comment: Using this formula is not the way exppected  value of binomial probablities is E(x)=npq so it becomes ,in this case, X(0.7)(0.3)

Comment: Your comment is non-sensical. $X$ does not have Binomial distribution. @HarshitGupta

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me please if this is a geometric distribution or not? I'm not sure. The telephone information service for a company is occupied by 45% of some. Let X denote the number of attempts that must be made  until the connection is established

Comment: @boomclap Yes, the distribution is geometric.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot.

Comment: @boomclap Welcome. You can consider clicking the tick mark to the left of my answer to approve it.

Answer (score -1):

a)$P(X=n)=XCn (0.7)^{X-n} (0.3)^{n}$

b)$E(n)=X(0.3)(0.7)$

c)$P(2 \le n \le 3)= XC2(0.7)^{X-2} (0.3)^{2} + XC3(0.7)^{X-3}(0.3)^3$

Here n is number of success (0.7) and X is number of attempts

Comment: This random variable does not have Binoimial distribution. $X$ can take **all** positive integral values. Your answer is wrong and misleading.

Comment: You are treating $n$ as the random variable and $X$ as  a fixed number. Totally meaningless.